# How to construct a SHACL shape using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, shacl

I have a `ttl` file with this information:

```
ex:Shape1
    a sh:NodeShape ;
    sh:property ex:Property-1
    rdfs:label "Shape 1"

ex:Property-1
    a sh:PropertyShape ;
    sh:path ex:property1
    sh:name "Property 1"

ex:property1
    a owl:DatatypeProperty
```

After loading the above data into my triple store (which contains many shapes already), what query can I use to retrieve the same data back?

I have tried a few things, the closest I got is the below query which returns every shape in my triple store (but not `ex:property1`):

```
PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
WHERE {
  ex:Shape1 sh:property ?propertyShape .
  { ex:Shape1 ?predicate ?object } UNION {  ?propertyShape ?predicate ?object }
  ?subject ?predicate ?object .
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query seems to do what I need:

```
PREFIX sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>
PREFIX ex: <http://example.com/#>

CONSTRUCT {
  ?subject ?predicate ?object
}
WHERE {
  {
    bind(ex:Shape1 as ?subject)
    ex:Shape1 ?predicate ?object
  }
  UNION
  {
    ex:Shape1 sh:property ?subject .
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
  }
  UNION
  {
    ex:Shape1 sh:property/sh:path ?subject .
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
  }
}
```